# LoRaWan module and Pixl.js

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, pixlr

noob question here. I am getting a

> unhandled promise rejection: AT+NETWORKID=13: TIMEOUT' error from an Espurino Pixl.js

I am simply trying to RX LoRaWan messages between two RYLR890 modules. One is being driven by the Arduino Uno, chirping `H` and `L` via the following code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(20);
  Serial.print("AT+RESET\r\n");
  delay(20);
  Serial.print("AT+IPR=9600\r\n");
  delay(20);
  Serial.print("AT+ADDRESS=1\r\n");
  delay(20);
  Serial.print("AT+NETWORKID=13\r\n");
  delay(20);
  Serial.print("AT+MODE=1\r\n");
  delay(20);
  Serial.print("AT+BAND=915000000\r\n");
  delay(20);
  Serial.print("AT+PARAMETER=10,7,1,7\r\n");
  delay(20);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("H");
  delay(1500);
  Serial.print("L");
  delay(1500);

}
```

The other is listening on a `Pixl.js` using the following code,

```js
var RYLR = require('RYLR');

digitalWrite(D9, 1); //VDD

Serial1.setup(9600, {
    rx: D12,
    tx: D11
});

var lora = RYLR.connect(Serial1);
lora.setNetwork(13).then(() => {
    lora.on('data', evt => {
        Terminal.println("messaged rx'd", evt.data == 'H');
    });
});
```

Any help with the `Pixl.js` (Espurino) code to receive the messages would be ideal. TIA. TS.

Answer (score 0):

In the Arduino code, you are setting baud rate as `115200`,
But on the Espurino Pixl.js code, the baud rate is set as `9600`.

Both of them has to be the same in order for communication to take place.

Comment: Thanks B45i for picking that up! I have since tried both on 9600 and both on 115200 with still no luck... any other ideas to try?? Much appreciated.